# react-native android app icons: why isn't the empty space around the image preserved?

Tags: react-native

I have created icons for a react-native app on android.

For example, this is the xxxhdpi icon. The black frame is not part of the image.
It is just for showing the white margins around it:

[image: xxxhdpi]

When I install the app, the white margins are removed and the image is displayed as follows on Android 8 (the black background is the wallpaper):

[image: icon on android]

I expected the white margins to be kept. How do I keep it?

---

Image by [Peri Priatna](https://pixabay.com/users/peri_priatna-8463731/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=3364909) from [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/?utm_source=link-attribution&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=image&utm_content=3364909)

Comment: Did you use https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher for generate the icon ?

Comment: No. I used https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-make. We (android studio and I are not friends)...

Comment: I don't like android as well try to follow this guide https://dev.to/sfarias051/how-to-create-adaptive-icons-for-android-using-android-studio-459h

Comment: Thx much! If I don't find a way to fix it, I will review it.

Comment: I tried to use android studio. Nightmare.

Comment: any luck, android + xcode is fun as hell :D

Comment: LOL :) I think that Xcode is much better. I ended creating icons using https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html. Seems to do it...

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz how about posting your first comment (link to the article) as an answer? I will not mark it as the accepted answer, but I will definitely vote on it

Answer (score 2):

I used the following instead: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html.

Great tool, did the job perfectly. Highly recommended.